# Windows file move error message

Tags: windows-7

Recently I get a file error when moving a file, If I hit the try again button the move completes, I also get this message when creating a new folder and hitting try again completes the new folder creation, it does not do it on a file copy.

I suspect a recent windows update to be the cause but would like a registry fix if possible.

Only thing I could find that is similar is [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/97de8a2a-12f2-4381-a409-a78f4ae551cf/cannot-create-new-folder-in-windows-7?forum=w7itprogeneral) but not sure if this reg fix will work for my issue.

Any Ideas?

Windows 7 64bit Dell XPS 8700

Edit: ran a chkdsk on the system drive and it found no problems.

[image]

Comment: this looks like NTFS issues so run **chkdsk C: /f /v**

Comment: chkdsk comes up clean, found no problems with the file system.

Comment: You always have the difficult ones don't you!!?

Comment: Nothing in EV, using MSE AV. Convinced it is a registry issue due to a windows update being installed.

Comment: @McDonald's if it was easy I would fix it myself!

Comment: To rule out a WU corrupting a system file, running `SFC /SCANNOW` from an elevated command prompt is simple enough!! It probably is a registry setting somewhere though.

Comment: running it now.

Comment: @McDonald's no, just a W7 system drive C and additional drive with Windows 10.

Comment: "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations."

Comment: please try a 3rd party file manager like Altap Salamander or Total Commander

Comment: Try disabling MSE AV and stop correlated processes to easily rule that out too. Absolutely nothing in any of the Event Viewers either? Also, check for Windows Updates again just in case there are others and considered looking at any optional ones that may be available too in case it's related. Just wild guessing and thinking of things I'd do. While I was at it I'd likely run ccleaner, run a variation of this [cleanup script](https://superuser.com/questions/1187299/windows-7-cleanup-before-clonezilla-backup/1187334#1187334), reboot, and defrag as well. I got ideas so might as well rule them out

Comment: What will a 3rd party file manager reveal? Nothing in EV, up to date as I am anal about this, defrag is always current, its registry issue that got borked with a Windows update. I am Leary of running scripts on my PC, as I am the one who has to fix anything if something goes wrong, that is how I have my current issue, something went wrong with a windows update and my registry.

Comment: simply try it with a 3rd party tool. Maybe they show a better error message

Comment: have you tried a 3rd party file manager?

Comment: Working on it, got behind on other responsibilities, hopefullt tommorow I will try Q-Dir

Comment: Ya, I know your pain man with being the one that has to fix the problems. When I was the main man for one company's 500+ computers (just the ones locally in the office), that script (or a variation of it) has helped me out numerous times, and I shared it with that guy in the post to help him out and apparently he found good use of it too. I figured a technical guy like yourself could read the logic, understand it, and adjust accordingly. I don't do as much PC support nowadays though but for the Windows 7 days it's just the common things squeezed into one script for resolving various issues.

Comment: Sorry I am Late to respond, I tried Q-Dir and get same error when moving or creating new folder....http://www.softwareok.com/?Freeware/Q-Dir