# Running incredibly low on disk space

Tags: windows, disk-space

Im running Windows 10 on a 2015 HP laptop. The C drive on it has about 27 gb of space, but im down to only ~600mb on it and this combined with the computer's already low specs has made working with it noticeably slower. 
Almost all my programs and all my files are located on an external usb drive. I run disc cleanup regularly and have already compress the drive. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Use the Cleanup Tool and then use the tool of your choice to visualize what's taking up your storage space and update your question

Comment: Replace the disk with a larger disk, ideally a solid state disk, and mirror the old disk to it using Macrium Reflect Free, Clonezilla, or similar.

Comment: Here's some helpful tips and a script that I've used on many Windows OSes which includes the Disk Cleanup from the script: https://superuser.com/questions/1187299/windows-7-cleanup-before-clonezilla-backup/1187334#1187334