# How to recover my unused space in C drive

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, virus, anti-virus, sql-server

Total size of my C drive is 265 GB, normally i don't store my data in this drive, just install a lot of applications. The day before yesterday, it had free space of almost 130 - 135 GB which i checked around a week ago, only i use my laptop and no new application is installed after that. The day before yesterday, suddenly windows showed me a warning message something like `You are out of memory.` Then i checked and found that my C drive is almost full, in fact few MB is remaining! Then i urgently uninstalled some applications, removed temp data etc and gained around 12 GB.

Yesterday i run my laptop very few time, but today i noticed the free space is decreasing in `C Drive` again and i started to find the reason, then i remembered, two days ago i run an exe file found in internet, but it didn't work as expected, but hanged my PC couple of seconds, then i ignored it. I suspect now, that file left any virus in my pc and the virus is doing something wrong now. I noticed in my C drive, there is a strange named folder something like `3500e567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440ZZZ...ZZ....Z.ZZZ` and inside it, there were many folders with the similar name and inside each sub-folder, there were 351(perhaps) files. And the sub-folders are keep creating!

Then using `Batch Command` i removed that main folder and then i installed a licensed anti-virus which removed some viruses after the scan. After then i recovered some more spaces by various ways and now i have `22.4 GB` free space exactly and no space is decreasing then.

[image]

I checked major folder's size in `C Drive` using `Batch Command` and the total of the sizes used is around 85 GB. So still `C Drive` is missing around 150 GB!!!

1. Can anybody please guide me how can i recover this space?
2. Also does anybody have any information about the virus which creates files & folders with the name like `GUIDZZZ...ZZ..ZZZ.Z` ?

FYI: I have checked the drive for error checking tool in windows with no success.

Comment: You are out of memory errors is an indication you have not assigned enough virtual memory

Comment: Check out my post here https://superuser.com/questions/1187299/windows-7-cleanup-before-clonezilla-backup/1187334#1187334 that also works well for Windows 10 to get back some free space.

Comment: People are more likely to read your question/answer if you format it so it is not a [wall of text](https://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Please read [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help) and [edit] your question to add paragraphs and bullet points ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, i have resolved the issue and i got back the unused storage of the C drive. In fact [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) solved my problem, using this tool i got to know which folder was eating my storage.

[image: C Drive]

There was a sql server database log file got increased suddenly to 150+ GB and the used size was not showing in the windows properties dialog while i check the size of the root folder `Program Files`, it was showing the used size of that folder without the file size of that database log file, don't know why, might be a bug of **Windows**! Now using [WinDirStat](https://windirstat.net/) i traced that file and i shrinked the database log file with the help of `SSMS(sql server management studio)` and now i have around 175 GB free space in my C drive :)

So my first issue is resolved. Still i didn't get any information about the second issue, as i have not suffered any more with this issue later, this issue could be ignored.

Comment: This answer will most likely help lots of people for years to come. +1 :-)