# What's up with the C:\Windows\Assembly folder?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, gui

If you go to the C:\Windows\Assembly folder on windows 10 (and possibly earlier versions as well) file explorer looks all weird. What's going on?

[image]

As you can see in the image, the menu at the top is different, the path is gone, and the name column says "assembly name".

In addition, the context menu is different, and the files cannot be opened.

Viewing the folder in powershell gives a completely different list of contents (pictured below)

[image]

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693689/what-are-those-stuff-in-c-windows-assembly-directory and https://superuser.com/questions/1292238/safe-to-delete-empty-folders-from-c-windows-assembly

Comment: @Ramhound the menus at the top are missing, the context menu is different, and the files cannot be opened. (adding these details to question)

Comment: Try the simple repair (DISM / SFC) and then we will go from there.  ...... (1) Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator.
(2) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /StartComponentCleanup
(3) DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /Restorehealth
(4) SFC /SCANNOW
(5) Restart when all the above is complete and test.

Answer (score 1):

You're seeing specialized view of the folder contents -- similar to the `Fonts` and `Recent Items` folders, which also have specialized views.

The folders all have a `desktop.ini` file (most commonly associated with specifying custom icons and language-specific display names) with a value named `CLSID` in the `[.ShellClassInfo]`:

**Assembly**:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
CLSID={1D2680C9-0E2A-469d-B787-065558BC7D43}
```

**Fonts**:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
CLSID={BD84B380-8CA2-1069-AB1D-08000948F534}
```

**Recent Items**:

```
[.ShellClassInfo]
LocalizedResourceName=@%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-21797
InfoTip=@shell32,dll,-12692
IconResource=%SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-117
CLSID={0C39A5CF-1A7A-40C8-BA74-8900E6DF5FCD}
```

The folders must have their `ReadOnly` attribute set for the `desktop.ini` file to be displayed, so if you want to see the actual files in **Explorer**, clear the folder's `ReadOnly` attribute in **PowerShell** using:

```
$dir = Get-Item c:\Windows\Assembly
$dir.Attributes = $dir.Attributes -band -bnot [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
```

and re-set it using:

```
$dir = Get-Item c:\Windows\Assembly
$dir.Attributes = $dir.Attributes -bor [System.IO.FileAttributes]::ReadOnly
```