# How to remove previous versions data from Windows Backup?

Tags: windows-10, windows-backup, previous-versions

So I checked my backup settings (shadow copy / previous versions). By going to “backup settings / more options.” I see some folders there to be included in this.

I decided I don't want a folder `d:\videos` to be backed up by this so I removed it. But now I am confused because it's data is still in `d:\FileHistory\username\computername\Data\D\`! I can't seem to make them disappear and they are taking up a lot of space!

I tried “Control Panel\System and Security\File History\Advanced Settings - Cleanup versions” and it deleted a lot of files but this folder remained.

When I right click on `d:\videos` I still have the option previous versions and I can choose some previous versions of this folder. Even when I removed this folder in backup options! Clicking Back up now does not remove it from `d:\filehistory` either. Rebooting a system did nothing.

How is this supposed to work?

Answer (score 2):

> **How to remove previous versions data from Windows Backup?**

1. From an admin elevated command prompt run [`FhManagew -cleanup 0`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829770(v=vs.85).aspx). Now check and confirm the files are purged as expected and move onto the below items for further cleanup.

---

> ### Further Cleaning Considerations
>
> *Still from admin elevated command prompt*
>
> 1. `CLEANMGR /D c: /SAGESET:100`
> 2. When the **Disk Cleanup Setting** window pops up, select the **Clean up system files** option, wait for the window to refresh and then go down the **Files to delete** section and then select all the
>      check boxes and then press **OK**.
>
>    [image]
> 3. `CLEANMGR /SAGERUN:100`
> 4. `VSSADMIN RESIZE SHADOWSTORAGE /FOR=C: /ON=C: /MAXSIZE=1GB`
>
>    > **Note:** *For #4 you can change `/FOR=C: /ON=C:` to be other applicable drive letters.*
> 5. `VSSADMIN DELETE SHADOWS /ALL`
>
>    > **Note:** *For #5 this will purge all shadow copies from all volumes.*

---

### Further Resources

- [FhManagew](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh829770(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [VSSAdmin](https://ss64.com/nt/vssadmin.html)
- [CleanMgr](https://ss64.com/nt/cleanmgr.html)
- [Windows Cleanup before Clonezilla backup](https://superuser.com/questions/1187299/windows-7-cleanup-before-clonezilla-backup/1187334#1187334)

Comment: Hello, sorry but this did not help. First it seems the wizard runs on C: instead of D: (even when I changed the parameter in first command to D: it ran on C: in 3). I did it all but nothing changed and the d:\filehistory still contains d\videos. Anyway even if this worked, does it mean VSS is broken and will fill user's drive with unneeded backups unless you do some crazy hacking like this? :o

Comment: @Vitas Well #4 should limit the amount of space you allow it to consume regardless so max size being 1 GB should mean it takes up no more than 1 GB of space. I'll have to see about getting this functionality setup on a non-C drive partition on one of the Window 10 machines I maintain to verify and confirm exactly how this works on non-C drive partitions. I'll update accordingly once I determine the specifics.

Comment: Please do test. I have it set to use drive D: only (Copy files to:)

Comment: @Vitas .... I'm not sure why I'm having trouble with this but I only see the "C" drive folder on `G:\FileHistory\<Username>\<PCName>\Data\C` for the default "C" drive for "file history" i.e. `filehistory.exe` but for the "Previous Versions" from this other "F" drive I created it on with the `System Protection` tab of the "System Properties" screen by turning it on from there and then selecting **Create** --> https://i.imgur.com/9BgFlFu.png. Now when I run `vssadmin list shadowstorage` I see if used some space but I do not see "F" in `G:\FileHistory\<Username>\<PCName>\Data\F`

Comment: @Vitas I suppose this means file history and previous versions are two different things and I may have had the two confused but I'm not able to determine how to turn on file history function for any other drive than the "C" drive which is the default for some reason thru the Control Panel GUI so I'm maybe overlooking something or need to dig more for some command line or PowerShell method which I'm usually better with than the GUIs oddly enough since I script all sorts of things and automate processes for a living for the most part. Maybe you can tell me what I'm overlooking so I can help more

Comment: @Vitas Okay, last comment and if I get time later I'll try to pick apart more but it seems the **File History** function is not too efficient and that `FhManagew -cleanup 0` deletes all but the most recent backup. In order to delete the folder in `~\FileHistory`, I had to Turn Off and then manually delete. Seems that the restore points VSS for entire volume is more efficient and more manageable once turned on via the GUI running `VSSADMIN RESIZE SHADOWSTORAGE /FOR=F: /ON=F: /MAXSIZE=1GB` allocates space just as expected and **Previous Versions** are available just fine... File History is flaky

Comment: Hello thanks for testing. System protection is indeed a different thing. It is responsible for restore points which are created usually before windows update or you can do it manually. I think there is system state in it and you cannot choose specific folders in it like in backup settings I talk about.