# C drive randomly shows low disk space pop up

Tags: windows, windows-10-v1803

Sometimes Windows 10 shows me the wrong disk space since upgrading to v 1803.

I have 18GB free on `C:`, but after some time it shows 5GB and the low disk space notification pops up. After I restart my PC it gets fixed.

Windows is doing this randomly.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1187299/windows-7-cleanup-before-clonezilla-backup/1187334#1187334

Comment: When you get the 5 GB alert, do you check disk space *at that time*? Browsers, Windows OS and other software write many temporary files.

Comment: Try to open Task Manager and check if a process called Audio Device Graph Isolation is running. I had an issue, where this was eating up all of my hard drive. In my case, rebooting also cleared some space, but only temporarily. You can read about it [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-performance/audio-device-graph-isolation-eats-up-memory/3366347f-f9ed-43de-9254-ee21937d2531).

Comment: yeah i checked but nothing false found.

Comment: Use a file system size viewer (TreeSize) or a script reporting the largest folders/files run at intervals as the issue progresses to find the item(s) that are growing the most.

Answer (score 0):

Updates maybe, could be not enough ram too, the computer will cache the data in file but still, 13 GB is a lot.

Try this program,

https://files.downloadnow-1.com/s/software/16/11/66/96/advanced-systemcare-setup.exe?token=1530543076_a5cdf87aad5c68872c3826a21905c3d0&fileName=advanced-systemcare-setup.exe

When you install it be carefull not to install dash freelane program by unclicking the option.

full scan your pc, all the useless cached files should be found and give you a bit more space

[image: Junk Files]

Plus the program has a cpu/ram meter so you will see if you are needing ram.

After you are done with your problem, uninstall it.
reinstall it when you feel the need. Rince, wash, repeat!

[image: Performance Monitor]

Comment: i already running ccleaner. but problem seems somthing else,its just happening randomly after new version of win10. but its seems ok now nothing happens till yesterday. but i realy wants to know what causing the isue